# How am I supposed to create a multiplication table for the commutator/Lie-Bracket operaton if $\left[X_1,X_2\right]=X_1X_2-X_2X_1=0$?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let's say we have the Lie-group of

$$\left\{X_1=\frac{\partial }{\partial x},\:X_2=x\frac{\partial }{\partial x},\:X_3=x^2\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\right\}$$

We have to create a "multiplication table" where the operation is the Lie-Bracket operation (also known as commutator)

But what I don't get is: Why should we get anything different than zero in the first place?

Let's say:

$$\left[X_1,\:X_2\right]=X_1X_2-X_2X_1=\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left(x\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\right)-x\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\right)=\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left(x\right)\right)-\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left(x\right)\frac{\partial }{\partial x}=\frac{\partial }{\partial x}-\frac{\partial }{\partial x}=0$$

And the funny thing is that I can repeat this for any arbitrary IFG

So where's my mistake?

Comment: $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} (x\frac{\partial}{\partial x}) (f)= \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(x\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}) = \frac{\partial x}{\partial x} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} +  x \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + x \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial^2 x}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually,\begin{align}[X_1,X_2](f)&=\left[\frac\partial{\partial x},x\frac\partial{\partial x}\right](f)\\&=\frac\partial{\partial x}\left(x\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)-x\frac\partial{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)\\&=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+x\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2}-x\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2}\\&=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x},\end{align}and therefore$$[X_1,X_2]=\frac\partial{\partial f}.$$

Comment: Ok makes sense, thanks. Idk why our teacher did this without f

Comment: I really think that it is easier to do the computations with that $f$ there.

Comment: More generally, $[g\partial_x,\,h\partial_x]=\left(g\overleftrightarrow{\partial_x}h\right)\partial_x$.

Comment: I have given a matrix "explanation" (surely not the base word...) to this property.

Comment: @J.G. Could you give a reference for the notation (and associated concept) $\left(g\overleftrightarrow{\partial_x}h\right)\partial_x$ I am not aware of ?

Comment: @JeanMarie $g\overleftrightarrow{\partial_x}h$ is short for the function $gh^\prime-g^\prime h$. You'll see it, albeit with $\partial_t$ rather than $\partial_x$, in physicists' discussion of the [Klein-Gordon inner product](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/51422) (which, despite the name, is positive-indefinite). Here, we just multiply $\partial_x$ on the left by this function.

Comment: @J.G. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, one can establish relationship

$$[X_1,X_2]=X_1\tag{1}$$

in a somewhat weaker sense using matrices.

Indeed, let $(P_n)$ be the (n+1)-dimensional vector spaces of polynomials with degree $ \le n$ with $$(P_0) \subset (P_1) \subset (P_2) \subset ...\subset (P_n) \subset ...$$

We are going to obtain (1) on any of the $(P_n)$. For the sake of simplicity, let us see it for $n=3$.

In this space, operators $X_1$ and $X_2$ are resp.:

$$\begin{cases}X_1: \ ax^3+bx^2+cx+d \ \mapsto 0x^3+3ax^2+2bx+c\\
               X_2: \ ax^3+bx^2+cx+d \ \mapsto 3ax^3+2bx^2+cx+0\end{cases}$$

whose matrices wrt basis $\{x^3,x^2,x,1\}$ are resp.

$$M_1=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0&0\\3&0&0&0\\0&2&0&0\\0&0&1&0\end{pmatrix} \ \text{and} \ 
M_2=\begin{pmatrix}3&0&0&0\\0&2&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

It remains to check that:

$$[M_1,M_2]=M_1M_2-M_2M_1=M_1$$